# Facebook Api - Albums/Photos/Comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I wonder if anybody knows an option for what I am currently having an issue with while using the facebook API. I am happy to use either the graph api or fql to get around this problem in the short term, I am already using both at the moment, with plans to look at realtime subscriptions before fql deprecates.

I am currently checking periodically for updates to a page, this includes comments that are on any post, photo, album, video etc.

Using fql this is simple enough for the main stream as the main post object contains an `updated_time` field, this updates when comments are made against it. I can then filter on that and get posts with new comments, with a second query in the batch to get the comment objects since that time. This gives me only what I need which can be processed quickly and facebook are happy because the processing time is very low. For the record, something like this works fine in a batch:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, created_time, updated_time, message 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = me() AND updated_time > 1433783133
SELECT id, time, post_id, fromid, text 
FROM comment 
WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #posts) AND time > 1433783133
```

However this becomes a real problem when looking at albums, the photos in those albums and comments on those albums. This is what I have looked at and found:

**Graph Api**

Looking at the graph api, you can't really get hold of the comments without looking at each post and using `since` - there is an `updated_time` field against both the album and the photos, however this does not seem to update with anything worthwhile enough to be used in this case.

Example using a nested query:

```
me/albums?fields=id,created_time,updated_time,photos{id,created_time,updated_time,comments{created_time}}

{
  "updated_time": "2015-05-26T19:12:18+0000", 
  "photos": {
    "data": [
      {
        "updated_time": "2015-05-26T19:12:13+0000", 
        "comments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "created_time": "2015-05-31T19:10:41+0000", 
            }
          ],
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can see the comment has a `created_time` of the 31st, but the `updated_time` of the parents both are not inline with this (other updates set those values, but not comments like they do in fql for the stream.)

Another downside of this angle, is that querying the updated time of the parents, will still give me too many children and is less efficient.

**Fql**

Using Fql is near impossible to get this data correctly also, the `modified` field has the same issue as the graph api `updated_time`. I was hoping there may be an option to get all comments at the album level then filer on that and work my way up, but there is no viable indexed field to query on to do so. It has to be by photo, when there is a huge number of albums and photos, this quickly becomes a problem when batching from `album` > `photo` > `comment` as it's very slow to go through this data looking for updates.

This is currently an issue I cannot see a way around with the current api, I haven't dug into the realtime subscriptions yet, but I don't see a relevant subscription for a page for this anyway?

Has anyone had a similar issue getting only updates from the api for a page photos? If so did you find a way around this problem? Because I'm fairly stumped.

Appreciate anyone's time reading that :)

Comment: The updated_time doesn't update once a lot of comments are added, which is a known limitation of the API - have you tried setting up realtime update notifications for new comments rather than polling? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3

Comment: @Igy no, I currently haven't looked at realtime, I can see a feed subscription on there but no album/photo related ones. If I can find no other option then I will need to test to see if this provides comments that are in albums, as in the standard graph Api does not show these.

Comment: After looking at it, my initial thoughts on reading the docs was correct, that there is no subscription for photos against a page (there is one for videos) - this seems like a really huge oversight, or a deliberate exclusion.

Comment: Photos uploaded to a page should appear as an Photo Page Post, as an update to the 'feed' connection of the page, AFAIK (separate to the 'photos' or 'albums' connection)

Comment: After setting up a realtime subscription (and getting test posts through it) - this was not the case, I added both an album, and a photo to that album. As you say, they were made available as a post if I used the graph API and accessed the `/feed` edge - however they were not sent through to the `feed` realtime subscription. Comments on those photos, do pull through correctly though, so I will be using a hybrid approach of the graph api albums/photos edge and the realtime stuff. Thanks for your responses :)